# getiing Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Aws\constantly()

Tags: sugarcrm

** i am using scheduler in sugarcrm.after adding some file getting error
    I got this error but have no idea where i made a mistake. It would be really great if you could help me 
    **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Aws\constantly() (previously declared in /var/www/html/axcessio/aws_new/Aws/functions.php:19) in /var/www/html/microservices/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php on line 22 **

```
class amiCleanup_schedulerScheduler
{    
    public function check_daily_reminder()
    { 
        $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= running");
        global $db;
        global $current_user;

        $queryTime = "SELECT NOW() nowtime,CURDATE() nowdate,CURTIME() nowti";
        $SchdlrTime =  $db->query($queryTime);
        $rowTime = $db->fetchByAssoc($SchdlrTime);
        $current_dt = $rowTime['nowtime'];
        $GLOBALS['log']->error(" Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= current_dt :: $current_dt");

        $top_query = "select a.id as job_his_id,a.name as job_his,a.backup_delete_date_c as delete_date,a.backup_id_c as backup_id,b.name as jd_name,c.name as h_name,c.host_type_c as h_type,c.aws_region_c as aws_region from phs01_jobs_history a,phs01_jobs_details b ,mhs01_hosts c,phs01_jobs_details_phs01_jobs_history_1_c d,mhs01_hosts_phs01_jobs_details_1_c e where d.phs01_jobs_details_phs01_jobs_history_1phs01_jobs_details_ida = b.id and d.phs01_jobs_details_phs01_jobs_history_1phs01_jobs_history_idb = a.id and e.mhs01_hosts_phs01_jobs_details_1phs01_jobs_details_idb = b.id and e.mhs01_hosts_phs01_jobs_details_1mhs01_hosts_ida = c.id and a.delete_ami_c = '0'and a.backup_id_c IS NOT NULL";

        $top_query_run =  $db->query($top_query);
        $top_query_count = $db->getAffectedRowCount($top_query_run);
        $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= top_query_count :: $top_query_count");

        while($query_list = $db->fetchByAssoc($top_query_run) )
        {
            $job_his_id = $query_list['job_his_id'];
            $job_his = $query_list['job_his'];
            $delete_date = $query_list['delete_date'];
            $backup_id = $query_list['backup_id'];
            $aws_region = $query_list['aws_region'];
            $api_key = $query_list['api_key'];
            $secret_key = $query_list['secret_key'];
            $h_type = $query_list['h_type'];
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*=job_his_id :: $job_his_id");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*=job_his :: $job_his");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*=delete_date :: $delete_date");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*=backup_id :: $backup_id");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*=h_type :: $h_type");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= aws_region :: $aws_region");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= api_key :: $api_key");
            $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= secret_key :: $secret_key");
            if($h_type == 'RDS')
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= inside if loop");

                $delete = $this->delete_RDS($backup_id,$job_his_id,$aws_region,$api_key,$secret_key);
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= delete :: $delete");
                $update = "update phs01_jobs_history set delete_backup_c = '0' where id = '".$delete."'";
                $update_run =  $db->query($update);
            }
            if($h_type == 'EC2')
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= inside if loop");

                $delete = $this->delete_EC2($backup_id,$job_his_id,$aws_region,$api_key,$secret_key);
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= delete :: $delete");
                $update = "update phs01_jobs_history set delete_backup_c = '0' and a.delete_ami_c = '1' where id = '".$delete."'";
                $update_run =  $db->query($update);
            }
        }

    }

    public function delete_RDS($backup_id,$job_his_id,$aws_region,$api_key,$secret_key)
    {
        $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= inside delete_RDS backup_id $backup_id");
        $RdsClient = RdsClient::factory(array(
            'credentials.cache' => $cacheAdapter,
             'version' => '2014-10-31',
             'region'  => 'us-west-1',
            ));
            if(!empty($backup_id))
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= result :: $RdsClient");                
                $result = json_encode($RdsClient);
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= result :: $result");
                try{$result = $RdsClient->deleteDBSnapshot(array(
                    'DBSnapshotIdentifier' => $backup_id, // REQUIRED
                ));
                }catch(exception  $e){$GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= error in delete snapshot caught in ctach block");}

                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= result :: $result");
            }
        return $job_his_id;
    }



    function delete_EC2($backup_id,$job_his_id,$aws_region,$api_key,$secret_key)
    {
                $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= inside delete_EC2 backup_id $backup_id");
                $EC2client = EC2client::factory(array(
                                        'credentials.cache' => $cacheAdapter,
                                         'version' => '2016-11-15',
                                         'region'  => 'us-west-1',
                                        ));
                                         $result1 = $EC2client->describeImages([
                                                     'DryRun' => false,
                                                    //'ExecutableUsers' => ['<string>', ...],
                                                    'ImageIds' => [$backup_id]

                                                ]);
                                      $SnapshotId = $result1['Images'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['Ebs']['SnapshotId'];
                                      $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= SnapshotId  = $SnapshotId");
                                      $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= EC2client  = $EC2client");
                                      $GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= describeImages result1 ::$result1");

                                    if(!empty($SnapshotId))
                                    {                
                                        try{$result2 = $EC2client->deregisterImage(array(
                                                                'DryRun' => false,
                                                                'ImageId' => $backup_id, // REQUIRED
                                        ));}catch(exception  $e){$GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= error in deregister image caught in ctach block");}
                                        $GLOBALS['log']->error("Delete Backup scheduler =*= result for deregisterImage result2 :: $result2");

                                        try{$result3 = $EC2client->deleteSnapshot([
                                                        'DryRun' =>false,
                                                        'SnapshotId' =>$SnapshotId , // REQUIRED

                                        ]);}catch(exception  $e){$GLOBALS['log']->error("Ami Clean Up scheduler =*= error in deleteSnapshot caught in ctach block");}
                                        $GLOBALS['log']->error("Delete Backup scheduler =*= result for deleteSnapshot result3 :: $result3");

                                    } 
                                return $job_his_id;                                    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i am using scheduler,, added these files which is causing this error require_once('modules/Users/User.php'); include'../microservices/vendor/autoload.php'; use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache; use Aws\DoctrineCacheAdapter; $cacheAdapter = new DoctrineCacheAdapter(new FilesystemCache('/tmp/cache')); use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

Comment: simple and clear error message, you are trying to use class/method with the same name but more than one and that shouldn't happen in PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the file 'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php' is included on twice. You need use include_once or it is even better to use a vendor/autoload.php